# How do I refer to a SHACL rule file in a Fuseki configuration?

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki, shacl

I want Fuseki sparql endpoint to infer new triples using SHACL rules in a file "rules.ttl".

From documentation in https://jena.apache.org/documentation/shacl/index.html

```
<#serviceInMemoryShacl> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label                   "Dataset with SHACL validation" ;
    fuseki:name                  "ds" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "" ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:shacl ; fuseki:name "shacl" ] ;
    fuseki:dataset <#dataset> ;
```

Is there some place in the syntax above to refer to the rules.ttl file?

Comment: Currently, the SHACL shapes need to be sent as part of the HTTP request. Post the file as shown in the documentation. Jena SHACL covers validation with complete coverage of the "core" and "SPARQL" constraints.. Rules are in the community group document and are not currently supported: https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/. You can use the Jena rules engine with Fuseki.